# error on calling go function from c

Tags: go, cgo

New to go here.  Tried to call go function from C but suffered some compiling issues

Here is the go script

```
package main
// #cgo CFLAGS: -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
// #include <stdlib.h> 
// #include "wrapper.c"
import "C"
//import "unsafe"
import "fmt"
//import "time"

//export dummy
func dummy() int {
    fmt.Println("hi you");
    return 0
}

func main() {
    C.testc()
}
```

Here is the wrapper

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int dummy();

void testc(){
    dummy();
}
```

When running it, got error

```
xyz@xyz-HP:~/learn/go$ go run reader.go 
# command-line-arguments
In file included from $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:0:
reader.go:30:14: error: conflicting types for ‘dummy’
In file included from reader.go:3:0,
                 from $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:
./wrapper.c:6:12: note: previous declaration of ‘dummy’ was here
/tmp/go-build528677551/command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_export.c:8:7: error: conflicting types for ‘dummy’
In file included from reader.go:3:0,
                 from $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:
./wrapper.c:6:12: note: previous declaration of ‘dummy’ was here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare `dummy` in your C file. Here's how I split your code to make it work. I put the C function exporting in an `.h` file, and the body itself in a `.c` file, and included only the h file in the go code.

**dummy.h**:

```
void testc();
```

**dummy.c**:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


void testc(){
    dummy();
}
```

**main.go**:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "dummy.h"
import "C"

import "fmt"

//export dummy
func dummy() int {
    fmt.Println("hi you")
    return 0
}

func main() {
    C.testc()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I ran it, got error `./main.go:33: undefined reference to \`testc'`

Comment: @codingFun how did you run it? I ran it with `go build -o dummy && ./dummy`

Comment: `go build` invokes `cgo` behind the scenes, generating wrapper files etc etc. you can run cgo directly on the code to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks @Not_a_Golfer, I ran it as "go run main.go" and got the error with loader/ld.   Ran it your way (using go build..), it works great.  Thanks again. I have accepted your answer and upvoted it!